# Calling A Loop Inside Of A Form

Tags: c++, forms

When I call a `for (;;)` loop it just makes my program not respond.
Im attempting to call a loop for keypress checking.
Such as

```
for (;;)
{
   if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0) & 1)
   {
      UpdateTest(); // <- A void that I created to update some words
   }
}
```

I've called this function inside of Form_Load - and it stops responding.
I've tried to call it in different places too, it just errors

Comment: If you are running this code on the GUI thread, then the GUI will lock up. You may want to run this in a separate thread. Just be aware that if you do that, you may have issues updating the GUI from a different thread.

Comment: How may I do this? Can you provide an example :)

Comment: You need to clarify "form". Winforms (.NET)? Win API? Qt? Something else?

Comment: ***and it crashes.*** It probably does not crash. Just becomes unresponsive because you are not allowing the windows message pump to execute and the GUI to update.

Comment: This is actually a little hard to answer given only this amount of code.

Comment: @drescherjm Should have been more clear; my apologies

Comment: @drescherjm I can supply more on command.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to remove the infinite loop. That is not going to work well in this type of program.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I'm using Visual Studio CLV Project; Is this good information?

Comment: If you are in a GUI thread, then let the GUI framework *notify* you when key presses happen, don't *poll* for them at all.

Comment: I think OP meant CLR. See: [Control.KeyDown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Correct, I could not remember for the life of me.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  I'm having some issues with *Control.KeyDown Event's* Where do I place this event, I've read what you have said, but It still does not help. Do I place the event's inside of  *Form_Load*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add an infinite loop to the processing of the UI. This will cause the UI to stop processing subsequent messages and then lose response. Instead, handle the keydown event.

> Do I place the event's inside of Form_Load?

No. You could add the [`KeyEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=net-5.0) like:

C#:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("KeyPress: 0");
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

C++ Sample:

```
\\.h
#pragma once

namespace Project22 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this->KeyDown += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventHandler(this, &Project22::MyForm::OnKeyDown);
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;
        System::Void OnKeyDown(Object^ sender, KeyEventArgs^ e)
        {
            if (e->KeyCode == Keys::NumPad0)
            {
                System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("KeyPress: 0");
            }
        }
#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->KeyPreview = true;
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
    };
}

\\.cpp
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <windows.h>
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    System::Windows::Forms::Application::Run(% Project22::MyForm());
}
```

Comment: Hello! Sorry, meant to send this before; *Keys->NumPad0* Keys had a red underline (an error). When you hover over it says "type name not allowed", Do I have to define something else?

Comment: Hi @Goose, The SAMPLE code is C#, I have added the C++ sample, you could use `Keys::NumPad0` instead it.

Comment: I presumed it was in C# considering that it looked different and was in C# on the link you provided, thank you! I will try this

Comment: And if this really helps you, please also feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer.

Comment: Sure thing! Theres just one issue, Im pressing Numberpad 0 and its not  showing a text box, is this an issue with how i set it up?

Comment: Have you enable the Num Lock? and then try to set [`KeyPreview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_KeyPreview) to true.

Comment: Num Lock is enabled, Its still not working (I have added this->KeyPreview = true) inside of InitializeComponent

Comment: Could you show a minimal sample here or on github for me to test? The above sample I added works for me.

Comment: I just had it all setup wrong, thank you :) EDIT: Sorry for the delay, I Just created a new project, due to be having api keys and stuff there